# Line integral and checking its path independence in three dimensions

Tags: calculus, integration, line-integrals

I have a following exercise, falling under the topic of line integrals.

Calculate the integral:
$$I=\int\limits_{\gamma} \sin(yz)\,dx+xz\cos(yz)\,dy+xy\cos(yz)\,dz$$
Where:
$$\gamma(t)=(\cos^{4}t,\cos t\sin^5t,\sin^4t)$$
$$t \in[0,12\pi]$$
I based my solution on a chapter devoted to "Exact differential", so the task there was a little bit different. I need to calculate the integral and checking for path independence is (as I have read) an easier approach to solve such problems.

My solution:

I check if
$$P'_{y}=Q'_{x}$$
$$Q'_{z}=R'_{y}$$
$$R'_{x}=P'_{z}$$
which would demonstrate that the integral is path independent.

And indeed, after calculating those partial derivatives, I obtain:

$$P'_{y}=z\cos(yz)$$
$$Q'_{x}=z\cos(yz)$$
$$Q'_{z}=x\cos(yz)-xyz\sin(yz)$$
$$R'_{y}=x\cos(yz)-xyz\sin(yz)$$
$$R'_{x}=y\cos(yz)$$
$$P'_{z}=y\cos(yz)$$

I write three conditions:

$$(1) \quad U'_{x}=\sin(yz)$$
$$(2) \quad U'_{y}=xz\cos(yz)$$
$$(3) \quad U'_{z}=xy\cos(yz)$$

From the $(1)$:
$$U(x,y,z)=\int \sin(yz)\,dx=x\sin(yz) + \varphi(y,z)$$
$$U_{y}'=xz\cos(yz)+\varphi'_{y}(y,z)$$
$$Q=U'_{y}$$
$$xz\cos(yz)=xz\cos(yz)+\varphi'_{y}(y,z)$$
$$\varphi'_{y}(y,z)=0$$
Unfortunately it does not look like a correct result. I presume, that $U(x,y,z)=xz\cos(yz)$ is not the integral of the above example.

I have the following questions:

1) What for do I need the information that
$$\gamma(t)=(\cos^{4}t,\cos t\sin^5t,\sin^4t)$$
$$t \in[0,12\pi]$$

2) Is my solution correct so far? If yes, what to do next?

Comment: First, notation: Is $P'_x$ supposed to be the partial derivative of $P$ with respect to $x$? If so, a _standard_ notation would be just $P_x$. Anyway: How did you get to $U=xy\cos(yz)$? Looks to me like you've shown that $U$ is something else, and here you're simply reading the wrong line, confusing $U$ and $U_y$.

Comment: Yes $P′x$ is the partial derivative of $P$ with respect to $x$. How did I get to $U=xycos(yz)$? You are right, I confused $U_{y}$ with $U$. How should I continue?

Comment: Well, whether you realize it or not you've found $U$ so that $(P,Q,R)$ is the gradient of $U$ (or in other words $dU=Pdx+Qdy+Rdz$...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your check has reveiled that the given vector field ${\bf v}$ is exact, implying that there is a potential function $U:{\mathbb R}^3\to{\mathbb R}$ with $$\nabla U={\bf v}\ .\tag{1}$$ It s a basic theorem of vector analysis that in this case the line integral in question is given by
$$U\bigl(\gamma(12\pi)\bigr)-U\bigl(\gamma(0)\bigr)=U(1,0,0)-U(1,0,0)=0\ ,$$
and this solves the problem at hand.

Since the given $\gamma$ is a closed curve it was not necessary to compute $U$ explicitly. For an arbitrary $\gamma$ we need the potential $U$ explicitly. It can be obtained in the following way: Writing out $(1)$ in coordinates we have
$$U_x=\sin(yz),\quad U_y=xz\cos(yz),\quad U_z=xy\cos(yz)\ .$$
From the first of these equations we deduce that
$$U(x,y,z)=x\sin(yz)+f(y,z)$$
with an unknown function $(y,z)\mapsto f(y,z)$. This  implies that
$$xz\cos(yz)+f_y(y,z)=U_y=xz\cos(yz)\ ,$$
from which we deduce that $f_y(y,z)\equiv0$, or $f(y,z)=g(z)$ for some function $g$ of the single variable $z$. This implies
$$xy\cos(yz)+g'(z)=U_z=xy\cos(yz)\ ,$$
and therefore that $g$ is constant, which we may choose to be $=0$. It follows that
$$U(x,y,z):=x\sin(yz)$$
should do the trick, and a quick check shows that this $U$ indeed satisfies $(1)$.

Given any $$\gamma:\quad t\mapsto{\bf r}(t):=\bigl(x(t),y(t),z(t)\bigr)\qquad(0\leq t\leq1)$$ we then have
$$\int_\gamma{\bf v}\cdot d{\bf r}=U\bigl({\bf r}(1)\bigr)-U\bigr({\bf r}(0)\bigr)\ .$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have two questions regarding it: 1) Why did you write that $g$ is a constant and not $0$? 2) Why did you substitute $(1,0,0)$ under $U$? 3) Then why do I need the info about $\gamma(t)=(\cos^{4}t,\cos t\sin^5t,\sin^4t)$ and $t \in[0,12\pi]$ in the exercise?

Comment: Thank you for the edited answer. 1) Did you get $U(1,0,0)$ by substituting $12 \pi$ (and then 0) into $\gamma(t)=(\cos^{4}t,\cos t\sin^5t,\sin^4t)$? 2) Could the task be finished after this substitution, since the $\gamma$ is a closed curve? 3) What if the $\gamma$ is not a closed curve?

Comment: @PeterKowalski: See my edit.